# ajax call stops when page is changed

Tags: ajax, forms, internet-explorer, jquery

I have a form and it needs to be able to switch back and forth from english to spanish. To do this I am using  `<a href ="page.php?lan=SP">` . In my code i have:

```
<?php
if($_GET['lan'] == 'SP'){
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['lan'];
?> (spanish form)
<?php
}else{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['language'] = 'EN';
     ?> (english form)
}
```

in the form i have a text box :

```
<input name = "PromoCode" type = "text" id = "code" style ="width:250px" onkeyup="PCcheck(this.value)" maxlength="10">
```

and a paragraph which gets updated with text saying whether or not what you have entered is a valid code:

```
<p name =" " id="PC" style="width:250px"></p>
```

where PCcheck(this.value) makes an ajax call to see it the value in the text box matches a code in my database every time a user clicks in the box.

In every browser that i use (safari, chrome, firefox) this works.
In IE it perfectly works initially, but when i click the link to change the language, the form loads however, tying in the text calls the function but does not update the p tag. My function looks like this:

```
function PCcheck(pc)
{
    //alert(pc);
   if((/^\s*$/).test(pc))
    {
    }else{
        $.ajax({url:"check.php",
            type:"GET",
            data:'code=' +pc,
            success:function(result)
            {
                if(result =='Valid' || result == 'V&acute;lido')
                {
       document.getElementById("PC").innerHTML = "<font color ='green'>" + result + "</font>";
                }
                else
                {
        document.getElementById("PC").innerHTML = "<font color ='red'>" + result + "</font>";
                }
            }
        });
}
```

check.php looks like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$lan = $_SESSION['language'];
include('../db.php');
$code = $_GET['code'];
    $query = "SELECT * 
               FROM table
             Where Code = '$code'";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($row['Code'] == ''){
            if($lan == 'EN'){
                echo("Invalid Code");
            }else{
               echo('C&oacute;digo no v&aacute;lido');
            }
        }
        else if($row['FirstName'] != ''){
            if($lan == 'EN'){
                $response = 'Used on ' . $row['RDate'];
            }else{
                $response = 'Utilizado en ' . $row['RDate'];
            }
            echo($response);
        }
        elseif($row['Date'] < $date){
            if($lan == 'EN'){
                echo('Expired');
            }else{
                echo 'Expirado';
            }
        }
        else{
            if($lan == 'EN'){
                echo('Valid');
            }else{
            echo 'V&aacute;lido';
            }
        }
```

as i said, it works in all browsers, and IE on the initial load, but not if i change the language (the form loads in the correct language, and the function is called, but it doesnt look like the ajax call happens).I have left out some irrelevant code, it is just this that is not working.

edit after a little more testing:
It stops making the $.ajax call. I have no idea why it would work the first time but not after clicking the language link. Also, after a page refresh it starts working again.

Comment: I also have a <a href ="page.php?lan=EN"> for when the form is loaded as spanish

Comment: There are no ajax errors returned. It seems to just be skipping right over the code. I have tried setting cache:false and using POST instead of GET.

Answer (score 0):

Typo in the javascript?

```
            if(result =='Valid' || result == 'V&acute;lido)
                                                          ^-- missing '
```